# Symfony 5 & FOSCKEDITOR : create a simple custom plugin, icon of this plugin does not appears in the Ckeditor toolbar

Tags: javascript, ckeditor4.x, symfony5

From a Symfony 5 website, I installed the useful bundle fosckeditor (CKEDITOR version 4).

All works fine, I get the CKEDITOR field on my page. Now I want to create a new simple plugin.

I scrupulously followed this [official guide](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/plugin_sdk_sample_1.html) and created a new plugin in the `<symfony_root_dir>/public/bundle/fosckeditor/plugins/` named 'timestamp' with some files:

[image]

In the `plugin.js`, I add this code:

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add( 'timestamp', {
    icons: 'timestamp',
    init: function( editor ) {
        alert('hello test ?'); // this alert appears when I load the page containing the CKEDITOR
        editor.addCommand('insertTimestamp', {
            exec: function (editor) {
                var now = new Date();
                editor.insertHtml('The current date and time is: <em>' + now.toString() + '</em>');
            }
        });
        editor.ui.addButton('timestamp', {
            label: 'Insert Timestamp',
            command: 'insertTimestamp',
            toolbar: 'insert'
        })
    }
});
```

And, in `<symfony_root_dir>/public/bundle/fosckeditor/config.js`, I added:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
    config.extraPlugins = ['timestamp'];
    // same result if instead I add the custom plugin via a string : config.extraPlugins = 'timestamp';
};
```

For this simple example, I copy/paste an icon from another plugin, here is the timestamp icon file:

[image]

Finally, I reload my page (reload + clear caches). But the Ckeditor toolbar does not change, the custom plugin appears nowhere.

[image]

I tried to add the button in the `fos_ckeditor.yaml` file like this:

```
# ...
fos_ck_editor:
    # ...
    default_config: main_config
    configs:
        main_config:
            # ...
            toolbar:
                - {
                    items:
                      ['timestamp']
                }
    styles:
        # ...
```

But the button of my custom plugin keeps missing in the CKEditor toolbar.
I have no javascript error in the browser console, I don't understand where I made the mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this configuration:

**app/templates/ckeditor.html.twig**

```
{% extends "base.html.twig" %}

{% block body %}

    <div class="ckeditor">

        {{ form_start(form) }}
            {{ form_row( form.content ) }}
        {{ form_end(form) }}

    </div>

{% endblock %}
```

**app/src/Controller/TestController.php**

```php
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextareaType;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use FOS\CKEditorBundle\Form\Type\CKEditorType;

class TestController extends AbstractController
{
    public function index()
    {
        $form = $this->createFormBuilder()
                    ->add('content', CKEditorType::class)
                    ->getForm();

        return $this->render('ckeditor.html.twig', [
            'form' => $form->createView()
        ]);
    }
}
```

**app/public/bundles/fosckeditor/plugins/timestamp/plugin.js**

```js
CKEDITOR.plugins.add( 'timestamp', {
    init: function(editor) {
        editor.addCommand('insertTimestamp', {
            exec: function (editor) {
                var now = new Date();
                editor.insertHtml('The current date and time is: <em>' + now.toString() + '</em>');
            }
        });

        editor.ui.addButton('timestamp', {
            label: 'Insert Timestamp',
            command: 'insertTimestamp',
            toolbar: 'mode,0',                 // toolbar group and index
            icon: this.path + 'timestamp.png'  // icon file (PNG)
        });
    }
})
```

**app/config/packages/fos_ckeditor.yaml**

```yaml
twig:
    form_themes:
        - '@FOSCKEditor/Form/ckeditor_widget.html.twig'

fos_ck_editor:
    default_config: test_config

    configs:
        test_config:
            extraPlugins: ["timestamp"]

    plugins:
        timestamp:
            path:     "bundles/fosckeditor/plugins/timestamp/"
            filename: "plugin.js"
```

**Screenshot:**

[image: CKEditor Plugin Screeshot]

**Plugin Directory Structure:**

**app/public/bundles/fosckeditor/plugins/**

```
timestamp/
├── plugin.js
└── timestamp.png
```

---

Relevant links:

- https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/plugin_sdk_sample_1.html
- https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/plugin_sdk_sample.html
- https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_ui.html#method-addButton
- https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_config.html#cfg-toolbarGroups
- https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_config.html#cfg-toolbar
- https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/youtube

Comment: I misunderstood some options in the `fos_ckeditor.yaml` file and the FormType file (especially the CKEditorType field in my case. I used the option `'config' => ['toolbar' => 'full']` who overwrite the `fos_ckeditor.yaml` toolbar options). Your simply and working example help me to find the solution, I valid your answer :) Thank you !